# PHP After Apache Shuts Down?

Tags: php, apache, centos

I'm running an Apache server on CentOS and would like to be able restart the webserver from a protected page using the following:

PHP:

```
<?php
ignore_user_abort(true);
shell_exec('sh sh/restart.sh');
?>
```

restart.sh:

```
service httpd restart
```

My question is if the web server shuts down and the PHP stops executing will the sh script continue running to bring the web server back online?

Comment: what happened when you tried it?

Comment: Running `service httpd restart` requires root, doesn't it?  I hope your PHP pages aren't running with root permission.

Comment: The PAM package might allow him to authenticate as root to do this. http://pecl.php.net/package/PAM

Answer (score 0):

You should be fine since Apache doesn't shutdown until after the command is issued. But if you really wanted to be safe, use [nohup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup):

```
shell_exec('nohup sh sh/restart.sh');
```

Answer (score 0):

If your PHP runs as apache module, then once you kill httpd your script will be terminated instantly. So you need to delegate restart to i.e. command line script (called using `exec()` or `shell_exec()`)

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to add an & at the end of the command. This will fork the process and run it in the background. This way it will not depend on apache still running.

```
shell_exec('sh sh/restart.sh &');
```

If this works, you should not need ignore_user_abort().